# Java GUI trouble on MacOS X with Netbeans

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, netbeans

I'm fairly new to GUI programming, and I've been trying to replicate an example where I want to have an array of JButtons right next to each other.

I set the vertical and horizontal gaps both to 0 in the grid layout and still there are spaces between the buttons. On Windows this problem doesn't really exist and you can get the buttons right next to each other.

Can someone help me with this please?

buttons = new JButton[3][3];
        buttonP = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3,0,0));

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
            buttonP.add(buttons[i][j]);
        }
    }
    add(buttonP);
```